# Windows Azure. Get unique application instance ID

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We use "Websites" in Windows Azure. I need to get unique application instance. I know about "RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id" but as long as I know it works only for web roles. So I'm thinking about the following way to get unique application ID for each instance. I'm interested whether it's OK to use. Or am I missing something?

1. Once the application is started I generate some unique name (in the "Application_Start" method). For example, Guid.NewGuid().
2. Once it's done I store this unique value in some static variable.
3. When a second instance in started, steps 1 and 2 are repeated and some other new unique name is generated

This way I have unique names for each instance. Of course, once a site (or some instance) is restarted I'll get new absolutely unique values. But it's fine in our case.

Please let me know if you find any pitfalls in this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the COMPUTERNAME or the WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID environment variables instead.

In fact, you can browse the full list of environment variables at `https://<yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env`

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but of course the GUID will only be around for the lifetime of the w3wp process. So you would have unique names per w3wp process which would imply that you would have unique names for each instance.

If you wanted to use a more targeted unique name, you could experiment with the ARR affinity cookie. Azure Web app runs with a sticky session load balancer (when running with multiple instances) by default. It injects ARR affinity cookie in the HTTP response that helps in redirecting a user to the same instance with which it established the session at the first time.

You can also use the environment variables to uniquely identify the instance, i.e. `Environment.ComputerName`.

Comment: The ARR affinity cookie and the `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID` environment variable are the same.